# android chess game example

Tags: android, chess

I'm wondering if there is an android open source code or tutorial in a book/blog for a chess game(can exclude A.I. as I would have to ignor it anyway as I am writing a game that would be similar but different enough to have to right my own A.I. anyway). I've done some looking and all I found was not of any real use because I can't read chinees congee, and even then those comments were very scattered. any help would be great, looking for a board game framework at the very least.